# "Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function"

Tags: java, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile this project (https://github.com/dennisss/mvision/tree/master/android) which is a success after changing minSdkVersion to 22.

However, the app only displays a black screen after running it. When I look deeper into the code, I can find several lines where the error "Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function" is displayed. (such as in /mvision-master/android/app/src/main/java/me/denniss/mvision/RecordingFragment, line 61)

I tried to solve the problem using answers on similar issues that I found but it didn't work, does anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the project as is in github or did you change the sources (in particular, is the package id the same)?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I did not change anything to the sources, although I successfully compiled the main project (I can run ./mvision on my computer).

How can I check the package id?

Comment: The package where you can find the Java code that calls the JNI function (stated at the top of the java file) should be the same as the package signature in the jni code. But, if you did not change the code, this is probably not the issue, the cpp library is probably not build or cannot be found. When you say you successfully compiled the main project, does that include the CPP library? Did NDK compiling succeed?

Comment: I compiled (I ran "make) the cpp library in the src folder and managed to launch it. The NDK compiling also succeeded although when I look into the code, it shows "Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function"... also, the app can be launched but I only get a black screen which is why I think the cpp library isn't included in the app...

Is there any other information that could be useful for you?

Comment: Have you solve the error i am facing the same error and am unable to solve it please help me if you have the solution?

Comment: Hope that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44225181/192373) can help.