# Cannot recognize native functions in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a simple face detection for android based on Dlib, I get this code from [Here](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app), I build project and it runs on my phone but it seems have got some problem, this code is made by Dlib and use some Native function, it shows me this Error (but this error doesn't stop build and I can generate APK).

For example I have this function:

```
@Keep
private synchronized native int jniDeInit();
```

and it gives me this error like a popUp above it:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crznw.png)

> Cannnot resolve corresponding JNI function
>   Java_com_tzutallin_dlib_PedestrianDet_jniDeInit , Reports native
>   method declartions in Java where no corresponding JNI function is
>   found in the project

Is there any config that I'm not using when I import someone project that's based on Native functions?

Thanks

Comment: This is not build error, this is static analysis from your IDE saying it can't find the symbol. That's pretty normal.  Try ```File -> Invalidate caches``` to see if it resolve problem.

Comment: @thachnb not working for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this post ([Cannot resolve corresponding jni fuction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431828/cannot-resolve-corresponding-jni-fuction)) says such things are not surprising and you can simply ignore it or suppress it. It will work at run time.

Comment: it's seems you're right , my fault in this code was in another place but i thought this warning/error/or_any_thing_it_is is the problem